# Drupal 7: theme_hook_suggestions lists the template but isn't using it

Tags: templates, drupal-7

I have a custom module for listing locations at several levels (radius zip code search, city-wide, state-wide, nation-wide). The templates for each level work fine but I'm currently trying to make an exception template for a city location.

My hook_theme() entry for that level has the template set as 'module--result-city' and in my preprocess theme I have:

```
function template_preprocess_mymodule_result_city(&$vars){
    ...
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'mymodule__result_city__' . $state . '_' . $city;
}
```

I add the state to the name since city names are duplicated throughout the country (dealing with US specifically).

I set $conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE; in my settings.php and looking at the source I see it has the right template file listed as an option but it uses the default module template instead.

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * mymodule--result-city--la-new-orleans.tpl.php
   x mymodule--result-city.tpl.php
   * mymodule-result-city.tpl.php
-->
```

In my test I'm using New Orleans, Louisiana as the city location.

I have tried placing mymodule--result-city--la-new-orleans.tpl.php in my root theme folder after it didn't work in my theme/templates folder. I've checked and quadruple checked the file name to make sure I wasn't just misspelling it.

I've also attempted to add a 'pattern' key to my theme array for that theme function but that did nothing either.

My current hook_theme() settings for this is:

```
$theme['mymodule_result_city'] = $base + array(
    'template' => 'mymodule--result-city',
    'variables' => array(
        'search' => NULL,
    ),
);
```

I removed the 'pattern' => 'mymodule__result_city__', line.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try using underscores in place of hyphens for the template in hook_theme. They get converted to hyphens when it searches for files anyway. Fixed it for me.